# Is there any way to customize the FBFriendPickerViewController in iOS SDK 3.0b?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

For example, If i want to add a search bar on the tableview in the FBFriendPickerViewController, what should I add in the programming code ?

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.friendPickerController.tableView.frame.size.width, 0)];
self.friendPickerController.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
[self.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

The attempt is not success. FBFriendPickerViewController is rather a convenient way, but....
IT IS IMPOSSIBLE TO FIND FRIENDS IN A EFFECTIVE WAY WITHOUT SEARCH BAR.....

Comment: It's a bad habit to give Minus on the topic

Comment: Good question but please don't shout. My ears hurt :(

Answer (score 2):

From the Facebook developer documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/add-search-to-friend-picker-using-ios-sdk/):

> Customizing the friend picker
>
> The default friend picker is displayed in the following way:
>
> - A done button is visible
> - A cancel button is visible
> - Friend profile pictures are shown
> - Friends are sorted by first name
> - Friend's names are displayed with the first name first
>
> You can customize these default display features by configuring the
>   relevant properties of FBFriendPickerViewController:
>
> ```
> // Initialize the friend picker
> FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController = 
>     [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
>
> // Allow the selection of only one friend
> friendPickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
>
> // Hide the friend profile pictures
> friendPickerController.itemPicturesEnabled = NO;
>
> // Configure how friends are sorted in the display.
> // Sort friends by their last names.
> friendPickerController.sortOrdering = FBFriendSortByLastName;
>
> // Configure how each friend's name is displayed.
> // Display the last name first.
> friendPickerController.displayOrdering = FBFriendDisplayByLastName;
>
> // Hide the done button
> friendPickerController.doneButton = nil;
> ...
>
> // Hide the cancel button
> friendPickerController.cancelButton = nil;
> ```
>
> You can also show the friend list for a friend of the person who's
>   logged in:
>
> ```
> // Initialize the friend picker
> FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController = 
>     [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
> // Get friend's list from one of user's friends.
> // Hard-coded for now.
> friendPickerController.userID = @"100003086810435";
> ...
> ```
>
> Note: The friend list for the friend may not show up if that friend
>   has turned all Facebook apps off.
>
> If you need further customizations, such as changing the friend picker
>   colors or adding more friend info to the display, consider building
>   your own picker.